# I want to run my micromax usb dongle in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: usb, usb-installation

I want to install micromax 3G Usb dongle in ubuntu 12.04 version, So please tell me all the possible ways, how to do it,

Location New Delhi,India

Operator Aircel

Answer (score 0):

If your insert the Micromax USB dongle, you will see a new listing in the network-manager. something similar to **New Mobile Broadband connection**. Click it and the network setup wizard will appear.

Select **Next** -> Select **Country** (India) -> Select **Operator** (Aircel / anything in the list) -> **Apply**.

Restart the network-manger, by `sudo service network-manager restart` and then try connecting to that network.

Comment: It's not working, waste